# cannot remove NaN from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array d (shape (2658,12)) having 77 NaN's in column 6;
`(d[:,6] != d[:,6]).sum()` gives 77.

I want to substitute those NaN's by a specific number (e.g. -1).

So I did:

```
for i in range(len(d)):
    if d[i,6]!=d[i,6]:
        d[i,6] = -1
```

After which I still have 56 NaN's.
`(d[:,6] != d[:,6]).sum()`now gives 56.

How can that be?

In case it's important:
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get interpolated values for these positions with nan values:

```
import numpy as np

# filling the matrix example
d = np.random.random([11, 8])
d[3, 6] = np.nan
d[5, 6] = np.nan

# take a column
column = d[:, 6]

# find anchor indexes where values are not nan's for linear interpolation
xp = np.where(~np.isnan(column))[0]

# take their values according to indexes
fp = d[:, 6][xp]

# then find indexes where values are nan's
x = np.where(np.isnan(column))[0]

# copy matrix to compare results
result = np.copy(d)

# do linear interpolation with numpy for x indexes using xp and fp
result[(x,), 6] = np.interp(x, xp, fp)

print(d)
print('---')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some really useful functions with numpy. Just look at this example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = np.array([[1, 2, 3, None], [None, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=float)
>>> d
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., nan],
       [nan,  3.,  4.,  5.]])
>>> d[np.where(np.isnan(d))] = -1
>>> d
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., -1.],
       [-1.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])
```

I think it is what you need.

In your example it will be:

```
d[:,6][np.where(np.isnan(a[:,6]))] = -1
```

Comment: My original dat has 77 nan's. After evaluating d[np.where(np.isnan(d))] = -1 I still have 77 nan's. I also get the error: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

Comment: And if you whant to process one particular row or column, for example, you can do it with slices: d[:,6][np.where(np.isnan(a[:,6]))] = -1

Comment: Does this work?
d[:,6][np.where(np.isnan(d[:,6].astype(float)))] = -1

Comment: Uau! It works. But instead of -1 assume I want to assign to d[:,6] the average of the neighbor rows, like `d[i,6] = (d[i-1,6]+d[i+1,6])/2`. I tried `for i in range(len(d)):
    if np.isnan(d[i,6].astype(float)):
        d[i,6] = (d[i-1,6]+d[i+1,6])/2` but it didn't work.
Suggestions?

Comment: The right way is to use numpy.interp. See the next answer with the example.